# How would I go about making this Handler class static?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-logcat

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(tag, "in handler");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
            case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                // DO something
                ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String s = "successfully connected";
                connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                Log.i(tag, "connected");
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuf);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

I need some help making this Handler class static, but I don't really know how.

Message I get:

This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (null)
[image]

Here's Logcat complaining:

Part 1: pastebin.com/xwy2zEPh

Part 2: pastebin.com/9UBSWyr2

Comment: Why do you think you need to make it static? Why not a top level class? What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: I haven't tried any thing but I got this message. It works, but the app crashes sometimes not allot. So I don't know if that's the problem http://imgur.com/jfEuU3q

Comment: What causes the app to crash? The message you posted in the image (you should post the text in the question, BTW) says that it would prevent the outer class being GC'd; unless you are running out of memory, this is likely not the issue.

Comment: It crashes when I go from my landing page into my bluetooth listview menu and go back. it crashes then, not always. should I post the memory graph when running the app?

Comment: I would post the logcat instead.

Comment: Part 1: http://pastebin.com/xwy2zEPh
Part 2: http://pastebin.com/9UBSWyr2

edit: forgot some at the beginning of the log

Comment: this time it crashed when I went on to the bluetooth listview menu and then hit the nav button on my phone (the one on the right, can't remember what it's called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The reason it was crashing allot was because I forgot to add

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean with *static* (which is probably not the right term) you want to create a different file, e.g. MyHandler.java, where you put

```
public class MyHandler implements Handler {

 private final ApplicationContext context;

 public MyHandler(final ApplicationContext context) {
    // Add Pre Condition for context not null
    this.context = context;
 }

 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(tag, "in handler");
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    switch (msg.what) {
        case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
            // DO something
            ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String s = "successfully connected";
            connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
            Log.i(tag, "connected");
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String string = new String(readBuf);
            Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

and then

```
 final ApplicationContext context = getApplicationContext();
 Handler mHandler = new MyHandler(context);
```

*N.B.* I made the assumption that Handler is an interface...

**Edited** Due to Andy's comment

Comment: Probably wouldn't work because of the `getApplicationContext()` call.

Comment: Yeah, probably. That *MyHandler* class would need the ApplicationContext as compulsory constructor parameter...

Comment: Also, [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is a class.